# Voltage drop across photodiode constant

Tags: photodiode

I'm making a photodiode circuit, but the voltage drop across the photodiode is constant no matter what light levels it's in. Is this just a faulty photodiode or could it be some problem with the configuration of resistors? It sounds like a problem with the photodiodes, but it's happened with 2 separate PDs, which makes me hesitant.

---

The datasheet was wrong and it turns out I had it in the wrong way. Thanks for your answers though!

Comment: With photodiodes, you measure the current, not the voltage.

Comment: You'll have to show a circuit diagram.  The voltage across a PD is logarithmic in the light intensity... I've heard this can be used to make a detector with wide dynamic range.. (log detector.)

Comment: If you're using the photodiode with a transimpedance amplifier you *want* it to have a constant voltage across it- otherwise you'll get really slow response times.

Comment: You apparenly didn't hook it up right, you're not measuring it right, or your expectations are off. Without a schematic this question is pointless and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the PD forward-biased. In that configuration, it behaves just like a plain old diode. You should reverse bias it, and look at the voltage across a resistor, like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo59do.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Acceptable bias level depends on your PD. Resistor value depends on your PD size and the amount and wavelength of the light being observed. Bigger resistor gives better sensitivity, but slower response. If speed becomes an issue, step up to a transimpdance amplifier http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn399f.pdf